# Applescript to Duplicate Files using My own application

Tags: macos

I'm developing a Mac OS X application and in some case it needs to copy a file to `/Library/ScriptingAdditions`.

And using the code below

```
tell application "Finder"
     duplicate sourcePath to destinationPath with replacing
end tell
```

will prompt a dialog saying `"Finder" wants to make some changes...`

I would like to make the dialog saying `My Application wants to make some changes....`

I've read about https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html

but it doesn't seem to work with AppleScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use the shell instead of AppleScript, the dialog asking for the password will display the name of your own application. Here's an example that copies the file "_this is a test.xyz".

```
set sourcePath to "'~/desktop/_this is a test.xyz' " -- mind extra space
set destPath to path to scripting additions folder -- change this to your destination folder
set destPath to POSIX path of destPath 
set destPath to "'" & destPath & "_this is a test.xyz'"
set shellScript to "cp -n " & sourcePath & destPath 
do shell script shellScript with administrator privileges
```

Warning: don't just run this script without modification, as it will add an empty file to your scripting additions folder and you probably don't want that. This script just serves as an example to look at.

**Edit:**

This will only work if you can compile your app as an independent app. If you're using Python, you need to compile your Python scripts as a standalone app with a name. The password dialog will show the name of the standalone app instead of "Python".

Comment: I use python package 'py-applescript' to call the script
But it will say "Python wants to make changes...."
I want it to say "My application wants to make changes..."
How could I do that?
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Just compile your Python script as a standalone app.